# How to close simple light box written by Animations on react native

Tags: android, react-native, lightbox, react-native-router-flux

I built simple light box by Animated.View . on my light box I put Button to close light box .How can do that.I dont want to use package like react native router flux

```
class Baselightbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        opacity:new Animated.Value(0)
      };
    }
    close(){  //here => how to close light box
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.opacity,{
                duration:3000,
                toValue:0
            }).start()
    }
    renderlightbox(){
        const {width=deviceWidth,height=deviceHeight/2,children,backgroundColor,Btitle}=this.props
        return(<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
            {children}
            <Button title={Btitle} onPress={()=>{this.close()}} />
            </View>)
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.opacity,{
                duration:3000,
                toValue:1
            }).start()
    }
  render() {
    const { height : deviceHeight , width : deviceWidth} = Dimensions.get('window');
        const {width=deviceWidth,height=deviceHeight/2,children,backgroundColor,Btitle}=this.props
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{opacity:this.state.opacity,borderRadius: 10,width,height,backgroundColor,padding:30}}>
{this.renderlightbox()}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: as far as i know... you need to call this.setState({ update state variables here }) and not this.state.variable...

Answer (score 0):

[My Code](https://github.com/AliNajafi1998/React-Native-Customized-Components)

Take a look at my codes :)